# Trouble with code to read muliple files in loop to read and special lines to import

Tags: excel, vba

I am really desperate to have your help to get this code fixed before end of today because my boss wants it to be done. I could not figure out how to set loop to read multiple files in .txt then import special lines to excel!! Please help me.

```
Sub ImportFile()
    Dim J As Long, K As Long
    Close #1
    Open "C:\TestFolder\TestFile.txt" For Input As #1
    For Each f In A$
        J = 1
        K = 0
        Do While Not EOF(1)
            K = K + 1
            Line Input #1, TextLine

            If K = 22 Then
                ws.Range("a1").Cells(J, 2) = Mid(TextLine, 20, 16)
            End If

            If K > 69 And K < 77 Then
                ws.Range("a2").Cells(J, 2) = Mid(TextLine, 1, 9)
                J = J + 1
            End If
        Loop
    Next
```

Comment: Can you show us the entire code you have got so far?

Comment: it is all i have ..i know that I need to add FOR EACH FILE AS FILENAME ETC but not know where to put in between code line?

Comment: My apologize as I noticed that above code is not  completed.. here's codes that are supposed to be on top of code Sub ImportFile()
    Dim J As Long, K As Long
    Close #1
    Open "C:\TestFolder\TestFile.txt" For Input As #1

Comment: @Teena please edit your post to include that code.

Answer (score 4):

You say: *I have looked through all questions and noticed that most of all questions got answers with script created?.. i am little confusion about stackoverflow's purpose to have this website for us? provide us scripts if we feel trap or trouble?*

There is a lot in this answer some of which will not make sense on first reading.  I believe eveything will make sense after a little study.  You may have to look up some VBA statements to understand what they do but I have tried to avoid anything too complicated.

There are many people answering questions so you will not get a consistent response to questions.

If your question is especially interesting to someone or if they have some suitable code to hand, they may give you a complete answer when they should not according to this site’s philosophy.

If you use a phrase that annoys people, you will be ignored or get rude replies.  “Can I do X?” annoys many here.  You are new to the site; how could you know you were being offensive?

We are not here to provide free code to anyone that wants it.  This site is about programmers helping other programmers to improve.  You are explicitly required by the site rules to have a minimal understanding of how to solve your problem.  Some answerers will take mercy and ignore this rule; most will not.  We are supposed to help you write your own new code or improve your existing code; not write it for you.

You have asked three questions within a day which seem to me to be different aspects of the same problem.  But it does not appear you have understood how to solve the first part of your problem or even that your problem has parts.

I appreciate the difficulties of having a boss demanding you solve a problem NOW that is totally outside your skill set.  Because there is so much available on the internet, your boss expects everything to be available.  You cannot find the exact solution to his problem so it is your fault for not trying hard enough.  **No it is not your fault.**  This is a unique problem so why would someone have coded and posted a solution for it?  I will be diplomatic and not say what I think of your boss.

My understanding of your problem is:

1. You have about 100 text files each containing some information you wish to extract.
2. The information to be extracted is lines 67 to 76.
3. You want to collect this information into a worksheet.  I do not think you have said if this worksheet is in an existing workbook or if the new information is to be added below previously extracted information in an existing worksheet.
4. You do not say how the information is to be arranged.  Do you want the 10 lines from each file spread along a single worksheet row or do you want one file line per worksheet row?

My understanding is that you have not got the solution to step 1 yet.  There is little point asking about extracting lines 67 to 76 if you do not know how to get all the files you want to read.  So let us try to solve part 1.

I tried searching StackOverflow and the internet for relevant code.  I got the best response for “How to read all workbooks in a folder with VBA” but it would be difficult (impossible?) for a novice to separate the relevant information from the noise.

Having no or almost no knowledge of VBA makes it very difficult to recognise what you want when you find it. The internet has many “Excel VBA tutorials”.  A large library or bookshop will have a computer section with a shelf full of how-to books some of which will cover VBA.  Please invest some time in background study.  That investment will repay itself very quickly.

A question like this might have produced a useful response:

*I have a folder containing 100 text files which I want to process one by one.  I am sure there are functions that will help but I cannot find them.*

This question is very contained and I believe someone would give a useful answer.  Do not forget to accept that answer because that gives points and reputation to the answerer.  You want to gain a reputation as someone who accepts answers so people want to answer your questions.  As soon as one question is answered and accepted you can ask another.  There is no limit on the number of questions you can ask per day.

You could also try opening the VBA editor, selecting *Help* then *Microsoft Visual Basic Documentation* then *Visual Basic Language Reference* then *Functions*.  Under that are all the available VBA functions listed in alphabetic order.  Most are of no relevance to your current problem.  The one you want is Dir or Dir$.  They appear identical but Dir$ is marginally more efficient.

I do not know how a beginner could find the other way of getting a list of files in a folder.  You need to look at the *Files Property* of the *Folder Object*.  If you search for VBA Help for *Files Property* you will get a long list of results.  One is *Files Property (Visual Basic for Applications)*.  Selecting that will give you a nice piece of relevant code.

VBA Help is a dictionary.  If you do not know a word exists and you do not know approximately how to spell it, you will not find that word.  You can have a quick look at each function, method and property and decide if any look interesting.  Some swear by that approach but I find a good book a better approach for me.  Your choice.

The Dir function is the older and easier approach.  However, you will need File System Objects for the next part of the problem so I will use that approach.

Create a workbook in the folder containing the text files if you do not already have a suitable workbook.  You do not have to have the workbook in the same folder but it is easier if you do and the macro below assumes they are in the same folder.

Open the VB Editor, create a new module and copy the code below to it.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test1()

  Dim FileSysObj As Object
  Dim FolderObj As Object
  Dim FileColl As Object
  Dim FileObj As Object

  Dim PathSearch As String

  ' This assumes the text files are in the same folder as the workbook holding the macro.
  ' Use PathSearch = "C:\ ..." if you would rather have the files in a different folder.
  PathSearch = ActiveWorkbook.Path

  Set FileSysObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set FolderObj = FileSysObj.getfolder(PathSearch)
  Set FileColl = FolderObj.Files

  For Each FileObj In FileColl
    With FileObj
      If LCase(Right(.Name, 4)) = ".txt" Then
        Debug.Print .Name & "  " & .DateCreated & "  " & .Size & " bytes"
      End If
    End With
  Next

End Sub
```

This macro displays a list of every file with an extension of “.txt” or “.TXT” in the folder PathSearch.  I have included the creation date and the size, which you do not need, to show there are other properties available.  This macro shows how to find the names of all the text files in a folder.  This is the solution to the first part of your requirement.

Part 2 of your requirement is to open each file, extract selected contents and close the file.

There are two distinct approaches to handling text files.  The older approach uses file numbers.  For example the open statement is:

```
Open pathname For mode [Access access] [lock] As [#]filenumber [Len=reclength]
```

The newer approach uses file objects:

```
object.OpenAsTextStream([iomode, [format]])
```

I will use the second approach because I want to use the ReadAll method.  This is very convenient providing the file is not too large.  You can read large files with ReadAll if you have enough free memory but if you only want a few lines near the beginning, it is not very efficient.

Once you know how to use File System Objects to access folders and file lists, using them to open and access files is relatively easy.  If you were trying to get your solution by asking a series of questions, you should try writing your own code for part 2.  If your code fails, you can post a question that seeks help with fixing your code.  That is the type of question that is most quickly answered.  Your error was probably a simple syntax error that an experienced programmer will spot instantly.  I am going to give you my solution to part 2.

Copy and paste Sub Test1 and amend its name to create Test2.

You will need some more variables so add this at the top of Test2:

```
  Dim File As Object
  Dim FileAll As String
  Dim FileLine() As String
```

In Test1 I used a `With` statement:

```
    With FileObj
      If LCase(Right(.Name, 4)) = ".txt" Then
        Debug.Print .Name & "  " & .DateCreated & "  " & .Size & " bytes"
      End If
    End With
```

This was easier than writing the equivalent without a `With` statment:

```
    If LCase(Right(FileObj.Name, 4)) = ".txt" Then
      Debug.Print FileObj.Name & "  " & FileObj.DateCreated & "  " & FileObj.Size & " bytes"
    End If
```

For my Test2 it would probably still be easier to use a `With` statement but it will not be easier for Test3 so I will drop the `With` statement now.

Replace `For Each FileObj In FileColl` to `Next` with:

```
  For Each FileObj In FileColl
    If LCase(Right(FileObj.Name, 4)) = ".txt" Then
      Set File = FileObj.OpenAsTextStream(1)      ' 1 means open in read mode
      FileAll = File.ReadAll
      File.Close
      FileLine = Split(FileAll, vbCr & vbLf)
      Debug.Print FileObj.Name & "  " & FileLine(0)
      Debug.Print FileObj.Name & "  " & FileLine(1)
    End If
  Next
```

With Test1, I identify each text file in a folder and prove I have done so by displaying each file's name.  With Test2, I have extended the macro a little.  It now:

- Opens each file.
- Reads its contents in a string.
- Closes the file.
- Uses function `Split` to break that string into lines.  This assumes these files use CR LF as line breaks which is the standard for Windows.  If this assumption is false, FileLine(0) will be the entire file and there will be no FileLine(1).  The next most likely line break is LF alone.
- Displays the first two lines of the file to demonstrate the macro has worked.

If experimentation does not help you find the correct line break character or string, you could ask a question like:

```
I have read a text file into a string and want to split it into lines.  I have tried:

    FileLine = Split(FileAll, vbCr & vbLf)
    FileLine = Split(FileAll, vbLf)

but neither works.  Please suggest how I can determine the line break string.
```

If I saw this question, I would suggest:

```
    Debug.Print Replace(Replace(Mid(FileAll, 1, 200), vbCr, "{cr}"), vbLf, "{lf}")
```

This converts CR and LF into printable strings.  It is most unlikely the line break is not some combination of CR and LF.  You could add this statement to Test2 to see what it outputs.  If that failed for you, I would come back with a more complicated diagnostic routine.

`Debug.Print` is a very easy way of showing a macro is working (or not).  Its one obvious limitation is that the Immediate Window has a limited size and early lines can be lost to make way for later lines.  I am not sure what the limit is but suspect it is less than 200.  In this particular case, seeing the last 200 or so lines will be adequate demonstration of success.  In other cases, this will not be adequate.  I will add a possible solution to my next "answer".

We now have a macro that solves the first part 1 of your requirement and part of part 2.

I would expect, you to be able to complete part 2 without asking a question.  Since all you need is a simple For-Loop, I believe you would find it difficult to construct a question that anyone would take seriously.

I would expect you to realise you need a new variable:

```
  Dim InxLine As Long
```

and to replace the two `Debug.Print` statements with:

```
      For InxLine = 66 To 75
        Debug.Print FileObj.Name & "  " & FileLine(InxLine)
      Next
```

I would have expected you to have noticed that the first line of the file was in FileLine(0) which why I have output lines 66 to 75.

With 10 lines per file, there is no possibility that all could fit into the Immediate Window.  As I said, this does not really matter in this case but might in another.  Probably the best choice is to have a diagnostic file.  At the beginning of the macro create a text file, write diagnostic information to during the run and then close it.  An easier technique would be to add another variable:

```
  Dim Count as Long
```

and replace the `For-Loop` above with:

```
      For InxLine = 66 To 75
        Debug.Print FileObj.Name & "  " & FileLine(InxLine)
        Count = Count + 1
      Next
      If Count > 100 Then
        Debug.Assert False
        Count = 0
      End If
```

`Debug.Assert` is a very useful diagnostic aid.  Normal use might be `Debug.Assert myVar > 0`.  myVar is being corrupted somewhere within my macro but I cannot find where.  I place `Debug.Assert myVar >= 0` throught my macro, and it will stop as soon as myVar has a negative value allowing me to investigate.  With `Debug.Assert False` the macro will always stop.  This means that every 100 lines or so, the macro will stop to allow me to examine the Immediate Window.  Clicking <kbd>F5</kbd> will restart the macro.

With this latest change, the macro outputs the lines of interest to the Immediate Window to prove that it can locate the lines of interest.

The final step is to output the lines of interest to a worksheet.  As I said you did not say what worksheet or how the lines are to be organised.  There are many answers that show you how to create a new workbook or open an existing workbook.  If an existing workbook there are answers showing how to find the bottom of any existing data within a worksheet so the new data can be added.  Because of this, I will do the easiest which is to clear worksheet "Sheet1" of the current workbook and write the data to it.

Add two new variables:

```
  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
```

Near the top of the macro add:

```
  With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ' Clear the worksheet
    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete
    ' Create a heading row
    RowCrnt = 1
    ColCrnt = 1
    .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Value = "Filename"
    For ColCrnt = 2 To 11
      .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Value = "Line " & ColCrnt + 65
    Next
    .Range("A1:K1").Font.Bold = True
    RowCrnt = 2
  End With
```

Replace:

```
      For InxLine = 66 To 75
        Debug.Print FileObj.Name & "  " & FileLine(InxLine)
      Next
```

with

```
      With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(RowCrnt, 1).Value = FileObj.Name
        For ColCrnt = 2 To 11
         .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Value = FileLine(ColCrnt + 64)
        Next
      End With
      RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1
```

At the bottom add:

```
  With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Columns.AutoFit
  End With
```

When you run this macro it should do approximately what you seek.

**Summary**

You must get a general grounding in VBA.  Without that, your attempts to construct a macro from bits of script on this or other sites will be like construction a letter in a language you do not know from bits of text in that language.

I have tried to show the importance of breaking your requirement down into little steps.  Getting answers to little questions is usually easy.

From the pieces of code you find on the internet or within Visual Basic Help construct a sequence of macros:

- Macro 1 proves you can achieve step 1 of your requirements.
- Macro 2 proves you can achieve steps 1 and 2 of your requirements.
- Macro 3 proves you can achieve steps 1, 2 and 3 of your requirements.
- :  :
- Macro n meets your requirements.

I hope this has helped.  Good luck.

Comment: Holy long answer batman! You have my upvote for such an in depth answer.

Comment: This is the epitome of a thorough answer. Nice Job!

Comment: @TheGreatCo Thanks for the +1.  (1) I took mercy on Teena because many years ago I had a manager like the pointy-haired manager in Dilbert who had no understanding of technoology and made the most ridiculous "requests".  (2) We get many questions like this where the OP has no idea where to start.  I wondered if it was possible to create some general advice.

Comment: @andy holaday  Please see previous comment.  Only one name allowed per comment.

Comment: Besides the kudos, I wanted to say something constructive. I am bookmarking this post and will probably send many new users to it to read and learn from, even if it's irrelevant to the question. It is a long post, but it has important information about how to be a better problem solver, how to ask more effective questions, and how best to engage the SO community. Seriously, nice job.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues right off the bat with your code, `1` is not a valid variable name (identifier).  Variable names cannot start with a number or a variety of special characters and cannot contain spaces.  You are also missing the `End Sub` in the example code, however I believe you have that already in your IDE as VBA won't even compile without it.  I have written a piece of code below that satisfies the requirement of being able to read the contents of a file line by line.   If you need to open a second file, you need to simply need to duplicate the code starting at `Open` and ending with `Close #A`.

```
Sub ImportFile()
    Dim J As Long, K As Long
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim A As String
    A = FreeFile()
    Open "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\movies" For Input As #A
    While Not EOF(A)
        Line Input #A, FileLine
    Wend
    Close #A
End Sub
```

StackOverflow isn't typically the place to get your code written for you, but we're glad to help you sort out specific issues.  If you have more questions once you have been able to read in each file line by line, you should post another question with the specific problem and your attempts to solve it.

Comment: thank you very much! for your time, i did not mean to ask for your written script for me, i just got myself exhausted figured out the script for two hours so i gave up.. white flag! .. but i believe this one is my last request for the script to be written. thank you! for big heart!

Comment: I have looked through all questions and noticed that most of all questions got answers with script created?.. i am little  confusion about stackoverflow's purpose to have this website for us? provide us scripts if we feel trap or trouble?